# $_POST disappears in IE and FF?

Tags: php, post

My $_POST value works in Chrome, and Opera, but when I open the same page, in IE or FF, it displays nothing. Even if I type in the URL the value, it doesn't work. Only if I write it in directly the PHP file. What could cause that?

```
if (isSet($_POST['check'])) {
    list($date,$room) = explode('/', $_POST['check']);
```

Thats where my code shows i have no `$_POST['check']`..

I open up this page like so:

```
<a href='?op=reserve&check=".$times[$c].'/'.$row["ID"]."'>
    <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/background/".$ico.".png\"/>
</a>
```

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: With information you gave us all I can say - No id does not dissapears.

Comment: Some code would help. By the way, POST does not pass values through the URL, only the GET method

Comment: $_POST doesn't contain any parameters you just type in the URL when opening the page.

Comment: Maybe it is not working because you are using post instead of $_GET?

Comment: @UglyEddie ,you was right. FF for some reason doesn't like it like that. So I changed the links and now its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write any value in URL it is not $_POST value but $_GET value.

If you launch url:

```
http://localhost/index.php?id=2
```

you should in your php code use:

```
$_GET['id']
```

to determine what's the value if id in URL

Comment: In Chrome, it becomes `2014-05-13/1`, but in FF `Undefined index`... (with _POST. With _Get its always undef.index.)
Like I said already, it works in one browser, but doenst work in the other one. Also works for my friend in the same browser where it doesnt for me.

Comment: You haven't defined $times[$c] or $row["ID"] in your script. If you defined it, show us those variables.

Comment: Thanks to you, I realized FF for some reason doesn't like my method, which was to use _POST, so istead I changed the links, and using now _GET.